# Set global variable in schema on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Rails 3.2 and MySQL. I would like to set some global variables for MySQL in my Rails app, instead of doing it manually the first time. Can I put this in `schema.rb`:

```
# schema.rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'MIXED';")

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20140202070057) do

  create_table "currencies", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

So that when I run `db:setup` for the first time, it sets the global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db/schema.rb` file is an auto-generate file. Instead add a migration script or rake task.

Example:

```
namespace :db do
  task :set_binlog_format => :environment do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'MIXED';")
  end
  task :setup => :set_binlog_format
end
```